# Redirect user to an android app after authorization

Tags: flutter, redirect, oauth, authorization, spotify

I am creating an app using **spotify api** and in the **authorization** link i need to pass **redirectUrl**.
How can I redirect user to my app?

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to your Spotify developer dashboard and open the project you are working on.

Next click `"edit settings"` and look for the redirect URIs field.

Put your redirect URI in the field. `ex: http://localhost:8888/callback`

Click save.

You should be good